# Don't prompt for another input if the previous was empty in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am working on an application, which basically implements `client-server` communication via sockets. On the client app, I have a `while` loop which continuously asks for input. It looks something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        # Send data
        message = input('You> ')
        if not message:
            continue
        print(f'Sending: {message}', file=sys.stderr)
        [...]
```

So when I send only f.e `ENTER`, then it doesn't send anything to the server, but still, I get the new line with another input prompt:

```
You> 
You>
```

So my question here would be: Is there a way to do this empty string check without having to write down another input prompt if it is in fact empty?

Comment: remove `continue` and replace wiht `break` to leave the `while True:`

Comment: Do you want to `break` the loop when the user enters nothing?

Comment: I think what they want is to re-prompt on empty input but without the prompt message being re-written

Comment: `if not message: input()` almost does it but adds a newline